# Kubernetes php web app with mysql and storing uploaded images

Tags: php, kubernetes

I've developed a web app for a client, and want to be able to use Kubernetes so it can be scaled as there will be a reasonable amount of users.

I'm a Kubernetes noob and am getting a bit stuck/going round in circles.

The web app is written in PHP, connects to a MySQL database, and users can upload pictures.  How should I structure this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials if you google that exact same combination of tools. You should do a bit of research and ask a more specific question. I also recommend running Kubernetes on your local machine and doing some experiments to get a good feel for how it works.

Comment: @cookiedough thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above you should be able to find a lot of resources online about this topic. As u mentioned you are new to Kubernetes so as cookiedough mentions you should spend some time on learning and testing this. You can do that in local machine using for example [minikube.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/) Other than that learn about deployments, services and auto-scaling in Kubernetes. You can find great tutorials and labs in the official documentation:

- [deploy PHP Guestbook application with Redis](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/)
- [Horizontal Pod autoscaler Walkthrough](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)
- [Article with explanation about deploying PHP/MySQL web application](https://medium.com/devopslinks/deploy-your-first-scaleable-php-mysql-web-application-in-kubernetes-33ed7ab66595)

If you will approach any problems during that process feel free to write a new question on stack with description what exactly went wrong and what steps led to that.

Comment: As I don't think I have time to learn enough about Kubernetes for the current project I am working on, should I keep my database on its own server but in the same data centre?  Basically say I wanted to migrate this project to Kubernetes later on, is there anything you'd advise me to do to make this easier?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, mysql is deployed at any physical host and you want to run multiple PHP containers. I have one query on how to store `images` across multiple PHP instances. 
You can create PHP `docker` image and deploy on k8s using deployment. 
The uploaded files need to be written on mounted host path so these are persisted in case of container failure.
According to usecase, the uploaded images need to be sync the uploaded files at central place.